# Difference between Tab Controller and Default Tab Controller

Tags: android, ios, flutter, tabs, uitabcontroller

What is the difference between a Tab Controller and Default Tab Controller? Can you please explain when to use Default Tab Controller and when to use Tab Controller ?

Answer (score -2):

Here I attach the official flutter documentation.

It seems to have the same utility, but if you want to compare their differences you have these two links:

**DefaultTabController:**
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DefaultTabController-class.html

**TabController:**
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html

I hope to answer your question, greetings.